# JBoss ValidateException: IJ010075: The resource adapter metadata must contain either an outbound or inbound configuration

Tags: java, jboss, jms

I am trying to run simple JBoss JMS example, but got this error

> Caused by: org.jboss.jca.common.api.validator.ValidateException: IJ010075: The resource adapter metadata must contain either an outbound or inbound configuration

I planned to  remove all the classes and add code gradually to see where the problem occurs but even with just this, it doesnt work

```
package rootPackage;
import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;
import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
 import javax.jms.TextMessage;

@MessageDriven(name = "MDBService", activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName =
            "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName =
            "destination", propertyValue = "java:jboss/jms/queue/ticketQueue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName =
            "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge")})

public class MDBService implements MessageListener {


public void onMessage(Message message) {
    TextMessage tm = (TextMessage) message;
    try {
        System.out.println("Get message " + tm.getText());
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        System.out.println("Error! " + e);
    }
}
}
```

I use IntelliJ, Java EE6 and JBoss 7.1.1. I added the queue to JNDI via web interface and run JBoss with

> -c standalone-full.xml 
>   option.

Answer (score 0):

Here a few points how you could start to find the origin of the issue.

1. check which resource adapter is configured in your JBoss, either via the admin console `http://localhost:9990` or in your `standalone-full.xml` (subsystem: `urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters`)
2. if a resource adapter is already configured open the `ra.xml` (inside the resource adapter *.jar, related to the error message it seems there is no section `<outbound-resourceadapter>` or `<inbound-resourceadapter>`

Comment: in Connector->Resource Adapters there are no items in the table, and there is no ra.xml file in my jboss folder.  When I click Container->EJB3  I can see: "Default Resource Adapter:hornetq-ra".  I can also say that this exception occurs when I deploy in Intellij an application that consists of separate .war and .ejb artifacts. There is no problem with single .war

Answer (score 0):

You should create WAR or JAR package, not RAR (which is for resource archive).

If you are going to expose some web content (including REST webservices) use WAR package, if you are about to write only business logic use JAR packaging.

If project is under build control tool such as maven just change packaging node value, otherwise change should be made in IDE.